# Slug for arabic alphabet

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor with jagi:astronomy for create mongo models.

When I create a document and the title is in the Arabic alphabet, the slug is never created.

jagi:astronomy Behavior

```
slug: {
    fieldName: 'title',
    helperName: null,
    slugFieldName: 'slug',
    canUpdate: true,
    unique: true,
    separator: '-'
}
```

This is how it is saved in the document
[image]

Comment: Given that Meteor is an actual service: did you contact their support? Also, given that https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy/ is open source, did you ask _them_ (through an issue) to see if that's because of their code, or because of Meteor?

Comment: To create slugs you need a transcription to Latin script. That's probably beyond the scope of your framework (just guessing, I don't really know it), but there're surely JavaScript libraries available.